# Why My ScrollTop Function is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, scroll, scrollbar, scrolltop

```
<script async> 
  $(window).scrollTop(1000); 
</script>
```

is async occurring problem here? first, it was in working condition then I put the async keyword in all script tags now it's not working.

Comment: Note: The async attribute is only for external scripts (and should only be used if the src attribute is present).

Comment: I have removed asnyc but it is not working